# how to save spark dataframe in tfrecords format i tried but giving error

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, apache-spark, pyspark

i am trying to save my spark dataframe in tfrecords format , but it's give error.

here is my command ,

```
df.write.format("tfrecords").mode("overwrite").save()
```

error message :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1095.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: tfrecords. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

spark version 2.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you run your Spark Job with the `spark-tfrecord` JAR . The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/linkedin/spark-tfrecord) provides some instructions on how to do that.

Comment: ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.linkedin.spark.datasources.tfrecord.DefaultSource could not be instantiated               now throwing this error